# About the $1$-norm and an M-matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm studying a proof about PageRank and I have some doubts. The proof states the following:

> If $\beta < 1$, and $P$ is a stochastic matrix for column (i.e. $ \lVert P \rVert=1$) then $I-\beta P$ is a $M$-matrix, diagonally-dominant and so its inverse is not negative. Moreover $\lVert (I-\beta P)^{-1} \rVert= \frac1 {1-\beta}$.

I proved that $I−\beta P$ is an $M$−matrix and diagonally-dominant. Does there exist a theorem that states that a matrix of this kind has an inverse that is not negative?. What about the last request? Could someone please help?

Comment: How far did you get trying to verify the claims?  It is best to identify a specific difficulty rather than asking someone to do all your thinking for you.

Comment: Ok sorry, i edited the question for my doubt. I proved that $I-\beta P$ is a $M-$matrix diagonally-dominant. Could you give me some hint?

Comment: As the wording of your exercise suggests, knowing the matrix $I-\beta P$ is an $M$-matrix and diagonally dominant does imply the inverse is nonnegative.  Diagonally dominant of course implies invertible, and for the proof that the inverse of a nonsingular $M$-matrix is nonnegative, see this [previous Question and Accepted Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989711/how-to-prove-that-an-m-matrix-is-inverse-positive).

Comment: Ok thanks, very usefull. What about $\lVert(  I-\beta P )^{-1}\rVert=\frac1 {1-\beta}$? Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part note that diagonally dominant matrices are invertible and see the previous Question [How to prove that an M-matrix is inverse-non-negative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989711/how-to-prove-that-an-m-matrix-is-inverse-positive)

Throughout we use the $1$-norm for vectors without explicit annotation:

$$ ||(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n)|| = \sum_{i=1}^n |v_i| $$

The final claim you need help with is the $1$-norm of the matrix $||(I-\beta P)^{-1}|| = \frac{1}{1-\beta}$.

Since $||\beta P|| = \beta < 1$, we have a convergent "geometric series" for the inverse of $I-\beta P$:

$$ (I-\beta P)^{-1} = I + \beta P + (\beta P)^2 + (\beta P)^3 + \ldots $$

Now we get by the triangle inequality (taking $1$-norms) that an upper bound on $||(I-\beta P)^{-1}||$ is the fraction $\frac{1}{1-\beta}$:

$$ ||(I-\beta P)^{-1}|| \le \frac{1}{1-\beta} $$

All that remains is to show this upper bound is exact, and for that it suffices to given an example.

In the Question you have written that "$P$ is a stochastic matrix for column".  Possibly by this you mean that the matrix $P$ is *left stochastic* as described in the Wikipedia article [Stochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix), i.e. that each column sums to $1$.  What this affects is the direction of the multiplication involved in defining the $1$-norm of the matrix $P$.  Since you skipped over that part quickly, you are apparently satisfied with the assignment $||P|| = 1$ based on the left multiplication, e.g.

$$ (1,1,1,\ldots,1) P = (1,1,1,\ldots,1) $$

If so, we only need to note that for $(I-\beta P)^{-1}$ we can say the following:

$$ (1,1,1,\ldots,1) (I-\beta P) = (1-\beta) (1,1,1,\ldots,1) $$

It follows that $1$-norm of $(I-\beta P)^{-1}$ being $\frac{1}{1-\beta}$ is attained by the vector $(1,1,1,\ldots,1)$ when the above equation is solved:

$$ (1,1,1,\ldots,1) (I-\beta P)^{-1} = \frac{1}{1-\beta} (1,1,1,\ldots,1) $$

That is, since $(1,1,1,\ldots,1) $ is a left eigenvector of $(I-\beta P)^{-1}$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\frac{1}{1-\beta}$, the $1$-norm is attained here:

$$ || (1,1,1,\ldots,1) (I-\beta P)^{-1} || = \frac{1}{1-\beta} ||(1,1,1,\ldots,1)|| $$

Comment: Very clearly, thanks!

Comment: When i see it now, it's not clear last two rows.  It's ok last equivalence that you row, but why we can conclude?

Comment: I "solved" the last equation to show that $\frac{1}{1-\beta}$ is an eigenvalue of $(I-\beta P)^{-1}$ and therefore a lower bound on its $1$-norm.  I also added a few clarifications (defn. of $1$-norm, etc.) earlier in my post, if not for your benefit then perhaps for future Readers.