# Non-diagonal Elements of Positive Definite Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix whose non-diagonal elements are all non-positive, determine whether all the non-diagonal elements of $A^{-1}$ are non-negative or not.

This is one problem of my final exam on linear algebra, and I didn't solve it during the examination.

I verified the cases of $n \leq 3$ and guess that this should be correct, but I don't know how to deal with non-diagonal elements of a matrix properly.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: One way to see it is the following: Observe that in the [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#The_Cholesky%E2%80%93Banachiewicz_and_Cholesky%E2%80%93Crout_algorithms) $A=LL^*$, the lower triangular $L$ has positive elements in the diagonal and all elements under the diagonal are non-positive. Apply induction and the recurrences in the link. Now, $A^{-1}=(L^*)^{-1}L^{-1}=(L^{-1})^*L^{-1}$. Observe that $L^{-1}$ has all entries non-negative ...

Comment: ... This you can see, by induction, from the recurrences for [Forward substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Forward_and_back_substitution), when you express $x_i$ in terms of the $b_1,b_2,...,b_n$ only. Therefore, $L^{-1}$ and $(L^{-1})^*$ have all their entries non-negative. Hence $A^{-1}=(L^{-1})^*L^{-1}$ has all its entries non-negative.

Comment: If you have heard about M-matrices or monotone matrices in the course you may know that they are [inverse positive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989711/how-to-prove-that-an-m-matrix-is-inverse-non-negative).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hints.* Let the diagonal part and off-diagonal part of $A$ be $D$ and $-F$ respectively. Let $X= D^{-1/2}FD^{-1/2}$. Justify that $X\ge0$ entrywise, $\|X\|_2<1$ and
$$
A^{-1}=D^{-1/2}(I-X)^{-1}D^{-1/2}=D^{-1/2}(I+X+X^2+\cdots)D^{-1/2}.
$$
The rest should be easy.

Comment: This kind of decomposition is extremely common for e.g. the graph Laplacian.  OP's matrix is essentially a non-singular Laplacian.  Not sure how I missed this.