# The inverse of an irreducibly diagonally dominant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I want to show that an irreducibly diagonally dominant matrix with non-positive off-diagonal elements has a non-negative inverse.

I already know how to prove an irreducible diagonally dominant matrix is invertible. However, I have no idea about the proof of the positivity of the inverse.

My attempt:
$A$ is invertible and $A^{-1}$ is nonnegative $\Longleftrightarrow $ If $Ax\ge Ay,$ then $x\ge y$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ If $Ax\ge 0,$ then $x\ge 0$

Comment: See one proof [given here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/989748/81360). I am not sure if there is any way to make this proof more efficient in your particular case.