# Condition on A for X to be positive when A X =b

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Given the following matrix equation: $$AX=b$$
with:

- $A$ a (n,n) invertible matrix ;
- $X$ and $b$ vectors of size $n$ with all elements of $b$ positive or null,

what is the condition on $A$ to have $X$ to have all his elements positive or null.

I wonder if the response is so trivial... (i also feel shameful to ask this question :) )

Comment: Square symmetric or  Hermitian matrices can be positive semi-definite.  I am not sure you can say that about vectors.  Are you asking about cases where all the elements of $\mathbf b$ and $\mathbf X$ are positive (or non-negative)?

Comment: yes, by semi-definite positive, i mean all elements of b and X are positive or null

Comment: Perhaps obviously, if $A$ is invertible then you want $A^{-1}\mathbf b$ to give non-negative results

Comment: yes right. i am searching for the conditions on $A$ to get $A^{-1}b$ to be positive or null on each of its elements.

Comment: If you want this to be guaranteed for all $\mathbf b$ with non-negative elements, then you need all the elements of $A^{-1}$ to be non-negative

Comment: Mmm... I may find matrix $A^{-1}$ with some negative elements that still gives a Positive x solution to the system. So you are right but this may be too restrictive...

Answer (score 1):

If we want $x$ to be nonnegative componentwise regardless of $b$, we need $A^{-1}$ to be nonnegative componentwise. Suppose not, then suppose $A^{-1}$ has a negative entry in column $j$, then we can let $b=e_j$ where $e_j$ is the $j$-th unit standard basis vector to construct a counter example.

You are looking for [monotone matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_matrix), matrices where if $Av \ge 0$ then $v \ge 0$ where the inequality is defined componentwise.

A subclass of monotone matrix is the [M-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-matrix). A [Z-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-matrix_(mathematics)) is a matrix where the off-diagonal entry is non-positive. An $M$-matrix, $A$, is a $Z$-matrix where it can be written as $A=sI-B$ where $s$ is at least as large as the maximum of the moduli of the engenvalues of $B$ where $B$ is nonnegative componentwise. Equivalence condition of $M$-matrices can be found on the wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-matrix).

Comment: Like i stated, $b$ is positive or null componentwise. So may be we don't need $A^{-1}$ to be monotone ?

Comment: If you want it to work for arbitrary $b$ that is positive or null componentwise, we need $A^{-1}$ to be positive or null componenentwise.

Comment: Beg my question: could you prove that last sentence ?

Comment: The first paragraph of my answer provides a proof.

Comment: I think your answer is right. The next question is then how to prove $A^{-1}$ is positive. At this stage, my question emerges as i have a specific linear system to solve with a need to get the solution x to be Positive. But this is beyond the question above...

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/989711/306553) is a proof of the inverse of $M$-matrices are nonnegative.