# Based on what condition a Diagonalized of a matrix could be all integer numbers?

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

I need to get a Diagonalized of a matrix. My given matrix is 4*4 strictly Dominant Diagonal matrix.
something like this:
\begin{array}{l}4&2&1&0\\1&5&2&1\\2&0&6&3\\1&1&0&3\end{array}
it seems the result of Diagonalized of matrix ( **if it is possible**) would be in form of ***A= S * D * S_inverse***. So now I really need to have the D matrix as all entries are integers not fractional. is there any way or any condition that **A as strictly Dominant Diagonal matrix** can have **D as diagonal matrix with all integers**?
I used this website for matrix calculation, it is hard to just try infinite numbers to get finally your desired output.
[calculator website](https://matrixcalc.org/)

EDITED
strictly Dominant Diagonal matrix : a matrix which items on diagonal is strictly greater than absolute sum of all items in that row, means
a_ii > Sum ( | a_ij | ) for all j, i != j
as you see in my example 4 > 2 +1 + 0 and 5 > 1 + 2 + 1 and so on

Comment: What is "strictly dominant diagonal"?  Is it the same as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/972725/show-that-the-inverse-of-a-strictly-diagonally-dominant-matrix-is-monotone?rq=1)?

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes, please see my edited also

Comment: If a matrix is similar to a diagonal matrix $D,$ the diagonal entries of $D$  are precisely the eigenvalues. For your matrix, those are irrational, not integers

Comment: I know my matrix is  just an example. I need to find a A matrix which D would be integers as well. any way I found one by lots of trial but I found there are a theorem.

Comment: If you are looking for examples, surely you should do it backwards. Pick a $D$, $S$ and just compute $A$. Here is an example with all integers: $A = \begin{bmatrix}6 & 2 & -2\\ 1 & 7 & -1\\ -1 & 1 & 5\end{bmatrix}$ which has eigenvalues 4, 6, 8.